# Enterprise Library Logging - display file and line

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

Does anyone know how to make Enterprise Library logging log the file name and line number of  where the message was written from? I am using version 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you might be interested in the stackframe class.  You'd want to build your message in the file that is calling the logging code as to get the correct information.

[StackFrame Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx)